# Aptana require not finding file in project

Tags: ruby, aptana

Hhey guys, I've been trying to pick Ruby recently and apparently Aptana is one of the better IDEs for use (I am spoiled by .NET and Java's IDEs).

So, I picked it up (having not want to splash out for RubyMine - RubyMine's IDE is based off of NetBeans which I never liked anyway) - and I'm having a  simple issue in my first project.

Aptana isnt' seeming to "pick up" my requires in the same project? I have a sneaking suspicion this might be something to do with how Ruby works (given that it has no main method), but I'll go ahead and ask it here because I can't find a definitely answer:

I have two files, `project_manager.rb` and `tests/project_manager_specification.rb`. `project_manager_specification` should contain behavioural tests for `project_manager`.

`project_manager` currently contains:

```
require 'tests/project_manager_specification'
```

`project_manager_specification` simply contains:

```
require 'test/unit'
```

however, when I run the application, I end up with this error:

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- tests/project_manager_specification.rb (LoadError)
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from C:/Users/dan.pantry/Desktop/Workspace/ProjectManagement/project_manager.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Which I don't particularly understand, because I can physically see that the file is there. Is it just not being loaded into memory, and if so, why not, and how can I get it to be loaded into memory?